# Line 7 Type error: Not all arguments converted during string formatting if (integerr % numberr) >= 1:

Tags: python

```
name = input("Say your name: ")
integerr = input(name + " pick an integer ")
numberr = input(name + " pick another integer ")
```

This is where I get my error

```
if (integerr % numberr) >= 1: 
    print(integerr + " is divisible by " + numberr) 
else:
    print(integerr + " is not divisible by " + numberr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes.

1. `input` always returns a string, as Simsteve7 mentioned. You can convert to an integer using `int()`, and convert to a string using `str()`.
2. You need to check `if integerr % numberr == 0`, because that means that `numberr` divides into `integerr` evenly; thus `integerr` is divisible by `numberr`.

Below is a solution for Python 2:

```py
name = input("Say your name: ")
integerr = int(input(name + " pick an integer "))
numberr = int(input(name + " pick another integer "))
if (integerr % numberr) == 0:
    print(str(integerr) + " is divisible by " + str(numberr)) 
else:
    print(str(integerr) + " is not divisible by " + str(numberr))
```

If you're using Python 3, you can use f-strings. That would look like this:

```py
if (integerr % numberr) == 0:
    print(f"{integerr} is divisible by {numberr}") 
else:
    print(f"{integerr} is not divisible by {numberr}")
```

Comment: Beside the point, but on Python 2, `input()` would evaluate (!) what it received from stdin. You want `raw_input` instead.

Comment: You don't need to do `str()` manually when `print()` can do it for you: `print(integerr, "is divisible by", numberr)`